# Query for Search Engine

Tags: jquery, mysqli

I'm trying to do search engine.

I want to found result when I start from `Band` or `Song_name`. But this query shows me result only then I start from `Song_name`. Is there something wrong with this query?

```
$query = "SELECT Band, Song_name FROM Songs WHERE 

CONCAT(Band,' ',Song_name) OR CONCAT(Song_name,' ',Band)

LIKE '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $search_text)."%'" ;
```

Comment: Could you format your question in a consistent way, please (read formatting help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your WHERE statements to the following:

```
$query = "
    SELECT
    Band, Song_name
    FROM
    Songs
    WHERE 
    CONCAT(Band,' ',Song_name) LIKE '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $search_text)."%'
    OR
    CONCAT(Song_name,' ',Band) LIKE '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $search_text)."%'
";
```